# When I click the button, I want to update the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create a process in which the database is updated by pressing the button. However, when you write it like the code below, when you click the button, it goes to the `admin_cp.php` page. The page froze, and the contents of the database remained unchanged. What's the problem with my code?

admincharge.php

```
<form action="admin_cp.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Charging handle?');"> 
    <input type="submit" neme="charge"/>
</form>
```

admin_cp.php

```
include('Aconfig.php');
if (isset($_POST["charge"])){ 
    $query = "UPDATE userinfo
        INNER JOIN chargeINFO ON (userinfo.u_id = chargeINFO.u_id)
        SET userinfo.u_charged = chargeINFO.u_chargewait;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if ($result) {
        echo "<script>alert('Charged complete.')</script>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=admincharge.php'>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('fail')</script>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=admincharge.php'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "page froze"? As in nothing is displayed? As in the page won't stop loading? PHP isn't really something that will generally "freeze", as it would usually time out eventually.

Comment: What deubugging have you tried?  If your initial test is not true, nothing happens, and nothing is displayed - this sounds like what you are seeing, right?  Have you checked if that test is really returning true?  It is false, because `neme="charge"` is a typo. I'm voting to close bcs typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked this part:

```
$query = "UPDATE userinfo
        INNER JOIN chargeINFO ON (userinfo.u_id = chargeINFO.u_id)
        SET userinfo.u_charged = chargeINFO.u_chargewait;";
```

at the end of .unchargewait;"; delete ; so it looks like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE userinfo
        INNER JOIN chargeINFO ON (userinfo.u_id = chargeINFO.u_id)
        SET userinfo.u_charged = chargeINFO.u_chargewait";
```